# How can I force BigQuery to autodetect schema with all strings?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to use `--autodect` in BigQuery forcing all new fields to be treated as `strings`?

The issue is the following: I have a `csv` file separated by `\t` and where all fields are quoted like this `'67.4'`. Now, if I simply provide a schema, then the `bq load` breaks for reasons I cannot understand. If I do `bq load --autodect` it works fine, but the values are still quoted. Now, I tried to do

```
bq load --autodetect --quote="'" --max_bad_records=10000 
--field_delimiter="\t" --source_format=CSV 
repo:abc.2017 gs://abc/abc_2017-*.csv.gz
```

But it now breaks wih

```
- gs://abc/abc_2017-04-16.csv.gz: Error while reading data,
error message: Could not parse '67.4' as int for field
int64_field_35 (position 35) starting at location 2138722
```

Here's one row, fields again are separated by tabs:

> '333933353332333633383339333033333337'    '31373335434633'    'pre'           'E' '1' '333933383335333833393333333333383338'  '2017-02-01
>   05:13:59' '29'        '333733333330333033323339333933313335333333303333333433393336'      '333333353331333933363338333033373333333833323338333733323330'                                          '3333343234313434'  'R' 'LC'    '100'   '-70.2' '-31.34'            'HSFC310'   'WOMT24I'   '146'   '1'     '05'

Ideas?

Comment: idea: can you provide sample data?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa: added one row

Answer (score 1):

[Auto detect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) schema samples up to the first 100 rows so if the column contains all integer for up to the first 100 rows then the data type will be integer. The purpose of [--qoute flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load) is to enclose the column with the specified value.

Example:

```
Sample csv data:
col1, col2
1, "2"
```

If you don't specify the --quote then by default it will be **"**. The data type for col2 will be Integer and the value will be 2.

If you specify the --quote other than the default **"** then it will enclose the data with that value. Example: --quote="'", col2 will be String type and data value will be **"2"** (the double quotes itself will be part of the data value)

As of now you can't force auto-detect schema to make all your columns to be of certain datatype, otherwise, it wouldn't be auto-detect after all. You may want to file a feature request to add another flag for bq load (and even in the UI) to make certain columns to be of certain data type (e.g. I want to make column # 1, 2, 15, 100, xxx to be String or All columns should be String/Integer/Numeric, etc...).